# Affecting elements declared before an element on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Given the HTML code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.one {height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: orange;}
.two {height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: yellow;}
.one:hover ~ .two {opacity: 0.5;}
.two:hover ~ .one {opacity: 0.5;}
```

I'm trying to do this: when one `div` is hovered over, it will affect the other `div`.

When I hover over `.one`, `.two` is affected. However, when I hover over `.two`, `.one` is *not* affected.

Why is this? How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` property. It affects the next sibling not vice versa.

```
.one:hover + .two {}
```